# Implementing Oracle's RAWTOHEX function in C#

Tags: c#, oracle, sql-function

I am looking to write the Oracle function rawtohex in C#.
I am looking at existing code that has been written and would like to be confirm if it is accurate.

```
public static string AsHexString1(this char[] chars)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var ch in chars)
    {
        int lowNibble = (int)ch % 16;
        int highNibble = (int)ch / 16;

        sb.Append(highNibble <= 9 ? highNibble.ToString() : ((char)('A' + (highNibble - 10))).ToString());
        sb.Append(lowNibble <= 9 ? lowNibble.ToString() : ((char)('A' + (lowNibble - 10))).ToString());
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, *RawToHex* should be something similar to this:

```
public static string RawToHex(byte[] data)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        sb.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", data[i]);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

I'm not sure why you're using a **char** array as input, since it's RAW data...

Comment: I'm not sure either to be honest as it is not my code. The data this is being performed on is stored in the db as char(80).

Comment: @pwee167 `rawtohex` is always performed on raw data. The database applies the function to the byte representation (cast) of the column in its character set. You may have character set conversion difference if your database doesn't use unicode (or the same flavour of encoding)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jigsore for this code. I was really struggling to convert a RAW value from a Oracle Object ID column to string format. I was having issues in Datagridview that was being populated with the datatable coming from Oracle. This function helped me to convert those OIDs to string value and also the output string value matches the value as seen in Oracle DB table.